# Datetime data type in a CASE expression impacts all other values on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, case

I'm attempting to insert a few rows into a table in SQL Server 2016 using the SQL query below. A temp table is used to store the data being inserted, then a loop is used to insert multiple rows into the table.

```
--Declare temporary table and insert data into it
DECLARE @fruitTransactionData TABLE
(
     Category VARCHAR (30),
     Species VARCHAR (30),
     ArrivalDate DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO @fruitTransactionData ([Category], [Species], [ArrivalDate])
VALUES ('Fruit', 'Apple - Fuji', '2017-06-30')

--Go into loop for each FieldName (there will be 3 rows inserted)
DECLARE @IDColumn INT
SELECT @IDColumn = MIN(ID) FROM FieldNames

WHILE @IDColumn IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --Insert data into Transactions
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transactions] ([FieldName], [Result])
        SELECT
            (SELECT Name FROM FieldNames WHERE ID = @IDColumn),
            CASE 
               WHEN @IDColumn = 1 THEN 1 --Result insert for FieldName  'Category' where ID=1 refers to 'Fruits'
               WHEN @IDColumn = 2 THEN 99 --Result insert for FieldName 'Species' where ID=99 refers to 'Apple - Fuji'
               WHEN @IDColumn = 3 THEN [data].[ArrivalDate] --Result insert for FieldName 'Date'
               ELSE NULL
            END
        FROM 
            @fruitTransactionData [data]

    --Once a row has been inserted for one FieldName, then move to the next one
    SELECT @IDColumn = MIN(ID) 
    FROM FieldNames 
    WHERE ID > @IDColumn    
END
```

When inserting the data, the data is inserted, but all the results show dates, when some data weren't meant to be dates.

```
+-----+------------+---------------------+
| ID  | FieldName  |       Result        |
+-----+------------+---------------------+
| 106 | Category   | Jan  2 1900 12:00AM |
| 107 | Species    | Apr 10 1900 12:00AM |
| 108 | Date       | Jun 30 2017 12:00AM |
+-----+------------+---------------------+
```

If I comment out the row insert of the date, the columns display correctly.

```
+-----+------------+--------+
| ID  | FieldName  | Result |
+-----+------------+--------+
| 109 | Category   | 1      |
| 110 | Species    | 99     |
+-----+------------+--------+
```

It seems like the insertion of the date converts all the result values to datetime format (eg. Jan 2 1900 12:00 is a conversion of the number 1).

The result I'm trying to get as opposed to the above results is this:

```
+-----+------------+---------------------+
| ID  | FieldName  |       Result        |
+-----+------------+---------------------+
| 106 | Category   | 1                   |
| 107 | Species    | 99                  |
| 108 | Date       | Jun 30 2017 12:00AM |
+-----+------------+---------------------+
```

Just for clarification, the `Transaction` table schema is as follows:

```
[ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_Transaction_ID] PRIMARY KEY,
[FieldName] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
[Result] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is making a guess at the data type for the `CASE` statement. It does this based on its internal [precedence order for data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) and the following [case statement return type rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#return-types):

> the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

Since `int` has a lower precedence order than `datetime` SQL Server is choosing to use a `datetime` return type.

Ultimately explicitly normalizing the data types of your case statement to `varchar` will solve the issue:

```
CASE WHEN @IDColumn = 1 THEN '1'
     WHEN @IDColumn = 2 THEN '99'
     WHEN @IDColumn = 3 THEN FORMAT([data].[ArrivalDate]), 'Mon d yyyy h:mmtt')
     ELSE NULL
END
```

In case you are interested SQL Server uses the following [precedence order for data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql):

1. user-defined data types (highest)
2. sql_variant
3. xml
4. datetimeoffset
5. datetime2
6. datetime
7. smalldatetime
8. date
9. time
10. float
11. real
12. decimal
13. money
14. smallmoney
15. bigint
16. int
17. smallint
18. tinyint
19. bit
20. ntext
21. text
22. image
23. timestamp
24. uniqueidentifier
25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
26. nchar
27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
28. char
29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
30. binary (lowest)

Comment: When I tested this on a SQL Fiddle, on its own, SQL Server was still trying to convert the formatted date to `INT`. I had to use the suggestion by @Ctznkane525 where the first two lines of the `CASE` expression were also converted to `VARCHAR` for it to work. Will test it on actual database tomorrow.

Comment: @mistaq yup I wasn't thinking about [case statement return type rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#return-types) and how it relates to [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) when I initially posted my answer. That's what I get for shooting from the hip. I've reworked the answer and hope it explains what's actually going on.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. And it worked on my actual database, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It is converting the format because all types in a CASE should have the same format.  I think you want to convert the date as a string (and the numbers too).

```
SELECT
        ,(SELECT Name FROM FieldNames WHERE ID=@IDColumn)
        ,CASE WHEN @IDColumn=1 THEN '1' --Result insert for FieldName 'Category' where ID=1 refers to 'Category Fruits'
              WHEN @IDColumn=2 THEN '99' --Result insert for FieldName 'Species' where ID=99 refers to 'Apple - Fuji'
              WHEN @IDColumn=3 THEN convert(varchar(MAX), [data].[ArrivalDate], 23) --Result insert for Field Name 'Date'
              ELSE null 
         END
    FROM @fruitTransactionData [data]
```

Comment: I think this works, though I've only tested it on a SQL Fiddle - will test it on my actual database tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

What you are trying to do just doesn't make sense.  The columns you are inserting into are defined by:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transactions]([FieldName], [Result])
---------------------------------^ -----------^
```

The `INSERT` is inserting rows with two values, one for "FieldName" and the other for "Result".

So the `SELECT` portion should return two columns, no more, no fewer.  Your `SELECT` appears to have four.  Admittedly, the first two are syntactically incorrect `CASE` expressions, so the count might be off.

It is totally unclear to me what you *want* to do, so I can't make a more positive suggestion.

Comment: Sorry about the extra CASE expressions - that's been fixed. What I want to do is to insert the 3 rows, but with each row having the correct data in the Results column. So the row with FieldName='Category' would have 'Fruit', row with FieldName='Species' would have 'Apple - Fuji' and the row with FieldName='Date' would have '2017-06-30'